# Best way to work out angle between points?

Tags: javascript, computational-geometry, mathematics

I have the following JavaScript code to work out the angle between two points (clockwise). The code I have seems a bit "hacky" to me, as I have a while loop ensuring the number is not negative (to make the range 0-360), as well as I have to subtract 270 degrees to get it to work correctly. Is there a better way to do this?

```
this.angle = function(point)
{
    var delta = point.subtract(this);
    var aR = Math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x);
    var aD = aR * (180 / Math.PI);
    aD -= 270;
    while (aD < 0)
    {
        aD += 360;
    }
    return aD;
};
```

Comment: The angle relative to what?

Comment: @Shmiddty That code snippet works out the angle between itself (this) and point. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: The angle has to be relative to something. The angle between two points is always 0. I assume you want the angle relative to the horizontal axis.

Comment: Oh for the love of pedanticism

Comment: @JoeFrambach It's important to know what he's expecting the angle to be relative to. If, for example, he's expecting it to be relative to the positive y-axis (12 o'clock), moving clockwise, that changes the calculation.

Comment: @Shmiddty You are correct in believing I am expecting it to be relative to 12 o'clock, and for it to move clockwise.

Comment: @jackwilsdon FYI: The JavaScript coordinate system has the origin at the top-left corner of the screen. Also, angles will be relative to the positive x-axis (3 o'clock), so you're going to have to rotate by -90 degrees to make the angle relative to 12 o'clock. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/RmyZg/  I shifted the origin, and flipped the y-axis, so that resembles the standard Cartesian coordinate-system.

Comment: Why the `a` prefix? How about meaningful names instead of `aR` and `aD`?

Comment: @retailcoder "Angle in radians" and "angle in degrees", I believe.

Comment: These aren't javascript, but you may want to look at these implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633177/c-how-to-wrap-a-float-to-the-interval-pi-pi

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, let's define the problem precisely.  According to your comment, this is the behavior you want:

> You are correct in believing I am expecting it to be relative to 12 o'clock, and for it to move clockwise.

However, your code doesn't actually behave that way.  Your `angle()` function, as written, computes the orientation of `point` relative to `this`, with 6 o'clock being 0°, angles increasing counterclockwise, with return values in the range [0, 360).  (Alternatively stated, your `angle()` computes the orientation of `this` relative to `point`, with 12 o'clock being 0°, angles increasing counterclockwise, with return values in the range [0, 360).)  So, I'm reviewing erroneous code.

As evidenced by the comments, many people had problems understanding what you meant by the "angle between two points".  That's a vocabulary problem.  I suggest that you borrow a term from navigation: [**bearing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_%28navigation%29).  In this review, I'll use the term "bearing" to refer to your desired behavior: when `point` is taken relative to `this`, 12 o'clock is considered to have a bearing of 0°, with values increasing clockwise, up to 360°.  I'll continue to use the term *angle* to refer to the erroneous behavior of your `angle()` function.

---

First of all, let's see how we can calculate the angle without having to do `aD -= 270`.  We can accomplish this by mapping the axes strategically when calling `atan2()`.  The direction for which we want the arctangent to be 0 is an "x′ axis" of our mapped plane, and the direction for which we want the arctangent to be π/2 we will call our "y′ axis".

[image: Axis-mapping diagram for nicerAngle()]

Here it is written out:

```
// Same behavior as angle(), but implemented without aD -= 270.
Point.prototype.nicerAngle = function(point) {
    var delta = point.subtract(this);
    var aR = Math.atan2(delta.x, -delta.y); // Mapped axes!
    var aD = aR * (180 / Math.PI);
    if (aD < 0) {
        aD += 360;
    }
    return aD;
};
```

Note that your `while` loop can simply be an `if` conditional.

---

Note that `Math.atan2()` is [guaranteed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) to return a value in the range `[-Math.PI, +Math.PI]`.  (See footnote below.)  We should now ask, is it possible to get rid of the conditional altogether?

One reason to get rid of the conditional is to reduce the number of code paths — fewer code paths means fewer cases to worry about in code-coverage tests.  Another reason is performance — if the CPU can always execute the code sequentially, then it doesn't have to do branch prediction.  When faced with a branch, CPUs speculatively execute code in advance, then throw away the results from the branch not taken.  (That's true for a low-level language like C.  It probably wouldn't matter at all for a naïve JavaScript interpreter.  It might make a difference on a highly optimized JavaScript JIT.  Anyway, the code-path-reduction argument alone should be a good reason to try to eliminate the conditional.)

Well, if we always add π to the value returned by `Math.atan2()`, then the result would be in the range `[0, 2 * Math.PI]`.  It's a simple matter of mapping the axes to make that work for us.  We want to map the axes such that 12 o'clock yields an `atan2` of 0° (our x″ axis), increasing counterclockwise such that 9 o'clock is 90° (our y″ axis).  If we can accomplish that, then adding 180° would map 6 o'clock to 0° and 3 o'clock to 90°.  Here is a diagram:

[image: Axis-mapping diagram for unconditionalAngle()]

… and a solution:

```
// Same behavior as nicerAngle(), but implemented without if-statement.
Point.prototype.unconditionalAngle = function(point) {
    var delta = point.subtract(this);
    var aR = Math.atan2(-delta.x, delta.y);
    return 180 + aR * (180 / Math.PI);
};
```

---

So, what about computing bearing?  Once again, we simply have to remap the axes when calling `atan2()`.  Using the same ideas as before,

[image: Axis-mapping diagram for bearing()]

```
// Computes orientation of point relative to this, with 12 o'clock being 0 degrees, angles
// increasing clockwise, with return values in the range [0, 360].  Implemented like
// unconditionalAngle().
Point.prototype.bearing = function(point) {
    var delta = point.subtract(this);
    return 180 + 180 / Math.PI * Math.atan2(-delta.x, -delta.y);
};
```

Of course, if you really wanted top performance, you could make this a one-liner by doing away with the intermediate `delta` object.

---

**Footnote about `unconditionalAngle()` and my unconditional implementation of `bearing()`**

Note that I said that `Math.atan2()` returns values in the range `[-Math.PI, +Math.PI]`, not `[-Math.PI, +Math.PI)`.  Therefore, with the unconditional implementations, it *is* possible to get a result of 360°, for example, with `ORIGIN.unconditionalAngle(new Point(-0, -1))` and `ORIGIN.bearing(new Point(-0, 1))`.  All I'll say here is that proper IEEE floating point math has a useful concept of negative zero.  I'll leave it to you to decide whether you want to deliberately stamp out this manifestation of that concept.

---

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvmMN/) of all the code above.